# How to iterate across lines in two files simultaneously?

Tags: python, iterator

I have two files, and I want to perform some line-wise operation across both of them. (In other words, the first lines of each file correspond, as do the second, etc.) Now, I can think of a number of slightly cumbersome ways to iterate across both files simultaneously; **however**, this is Python, so I imagine that there is some syntactic shorthand.

In other words, is there some simple way to adapt the

```
for line in file:
```

so that it pulls data from both files simultaneously?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Python 2:

Use `itertools.izip` to join the two iterators.

```
from itertools import izip
for line_from_file_1, line_from_file_2 in izip(open(file_1), open(file_2)):
```

If the files are of unequal length, use `izip_longest`.

In Python 3, use `zip` and `zip_longest` instead. Also, use a `with` to open files, so that closing is handled automatically even in case of errors.

```
with open(file1name) as file1, open(file2name) as file2:
    for line1, line2 in zip(file1, file2):
        #do stuff
```

Comment: + for using izip instead of zip

Comment: In Python 3, you need to use `zip`.

Comment: In Python 3, use `itertools.zip_longest` if you want to consume lines up to end of the longest file.

Answer (score 10):

You could try

```
for line1, line2 in zip(file1, file2):
    #do stuff
```

Careful though, this loop will exit when the shorter file ends.

When using Python 2, `itertools.izip` is better for this sort of thing because it doesn't create a `list`.

Comment: `zip` is okay if you use Python 3 (which probably didn't exist when you replied). Editing.

Answer (score 3):

A complete example for posterity:

```
from itertools import izip, izip_longest

file1name = '/some/path/and/file'
file2name = '/another/path/and/another/file'

with open(file1name) as file1, open(file2name) as file2:
    for line1, line2 in izip(file1, file2):   # or izip_longest
        # do something with the lines
```

Using `with` ensures the files are cleaned up after use, even if an exception occurs.