# Comparing 2 files line by line

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 2 file of the following form:

```
file1:
work1
7 8 9 10 11
1 2 3 4  5
6 7 8 9  10

file2:
work2
2 3 4 5 5
2 4 7 8 9
work1
7 8 9 10 11
1 2 4 4  5
6 7 8 9  10
work3
1 7 8 9 10
```

Now I want to compare to file and wherever say the header (work1) is equal..I want to compare the subsequent sections and print the line at which the difference is found. E.g.

```
 work1 (file1)
7 8 9 10 11
1 2 3 4  5
6 7 8 9  10

work1 (file2)
7 8 9 10 11
1 2 4 4  5
6 7 8 9  10
```

Now I want to print the line where difference occurs i.e. "1 2 4 4  5"

For doing so I have written the following code:

```
with open("file1",) as r, open("file2") as w:
    for line in r:
        if "work1" in line:
            for line1 in w:
                if "work1" in line1:
                        print "work1"
```

However, from here on I am confused as to how can I read both the files parallely. Can someone please help me with this...as I am not getting after comparing "work1"'s how should I read the files parallelly

Comment: read both into memory (each r.read() and w.read() into a variable), then do the comparison. Parallel is not the right word.

Comment: CppLearner The approach is feasible only when my files are not large for large files the approach is not feasible

Comment: Good point. Well, if you are sure the header such as `work1` is not repeated in the same file, then you can just open the file and read where the substring occurs and ends and the next header occurs. Record them in both files and then read. i don't know how the performance is compared to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322419/iterate-across-lines-in-two-files-simultaneously-in-python  which reads both files into the same iterator.

Comment: Looks like a job for a database.

Comment: Is your goal to mimic `diff` such as http://winmerge.org/ ? Or you only care about the first difference, and quit?

Answer (score 1):

You would probably want to try out `itertools` module in Python.
It contains a function called `izip` that can do what you need, along with a function called `islice`. You can iterate through the second file until you hit the header you were looking for, and you could slice the header up.

Here's a bit of the code.

```
from itertools import *    

w = open('file2')
for (i,line) in enumerate(w):
  if "work1" in line:
    iter2 = islice(open('file2'), i, None, 1) # Starts at the correct line

f = open('file1')
for (line1,line2) in izip(f,iter2):
  print line1, line2 # Place your comparisons of the two lines here.
```

You're guaranteed now that on the first run through of the loop you'll get "work1" on both lines. After that you can compare. Since `f` is shorter than `w`, the iterator will exhaust itself and stop once you hit the end of `f`.

Hopefully I explained that well.

EDIT: Added import statement.

EDIT: We need to reopen file2. This is because iterating through iterables in Python consumes the iterable. So, we need to pass a brand new one to `islice` so it works!

Comment: `islice(w, i, None, 1)` skips `i` lines starting from the current position in the file.

Comment: @AVP Thanks for the reply ...can you please explain the function of "islice". Actually its giving me error..name 'islice' is not defined. Also i have imported itertools..still I am not getting as to why is it throwing error

Comment: Are you doing itertools.islice or are you doing islice?
The second one will only work if your import statement is "from itertools import *", whereas the first will work when you do "import itertools".

Comment: My problem is that "for (line1,line2) in izip(f,iter2):
  print line1, line2" does not print any lines here. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Try simply iterating through iter2. Does that print anything?

Comment: No even while iterating through iter2 it does not print anything. Although I tried to print line after: 'if "work1" in line' and the line gets printed. However, I am not able to iterate through iter2

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('f1.csv') as f1, open('f2.csv') as f2 :
    i=0
    break_needed = False
    while True :
        r1, r2 = f1.readline(), f2.readline()
        if len(r1) == 0 :
            print "eof found for f1"
            break_needed = True
        if len(r2) == 0 :
            print "eof found for f2"
            break_needed = True
        if break_needed : 
            break
        i += 1
        if r1 != r2 :
            print " line %i"%i
            print "file 1 : " + r1
            print "file 2 : " + r2
```