# Python - Writing to a new file from another file

Tags: python, file, function, input

I wish to have to have the first field (Username) from File1 and the second field(Password) output into a third file which is created during the function but I am unable to do it. :(

The format of the files will always be the same which are:

File 1:

```
Username:DOB:Firstname:Lastname:::
```

File2:

```
Lastname:Password
```

My current code:

```
def merge(f1,f2,f3):
   with open(f3, "a") as outputFile:
      with open(f1) as usernameFile:
         for line in usernameFile:
            line = line[:-3]
            username = line.split(':')
            outputFile.write(username[0])
      with open(f2) as passwordFile:
         for line in passwordFile:
            password = line.split(':')
            outputFile.write(password[1])

merge('file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'output.txt')
```

I want the Username from File1 and the Password from File2 to write to File3 with the layout:

```
Username:Password
Username:Password
Username:Password
```

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: From File2, I want the `Username` string cut from File1, and the `Password` string cut from File2 and output into File3 which is made during the function.

Comment: Are the files sorted in the same way (the same users at the same lines?)

Comment: The format of the files will always be the same, but the content inside will always be different files with different data.

Comment: Does line 1 in both files always have the data for the same User? - how about lines 2-*?

Comment: No, the users and data will be different each time the script/function are run but the format is identical with (Username:DOB:Firstname:Secondname) and (Lastname:Password).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the minimum change that you would need to do to your code to make it work:

```
def merge(f1,f2,f3):
  with open(f3, "a") as outputFile:

     with open(f1) as usernameFile:
        for line in usernameFile:
           username = line.split(':')[0]
           lastname = line.split(':')[3]
           outputFile.write(username)

        with open(f2) as passwordFile: 
           for line in passwordFile:
              lN, password = line.split(':')
              if lN == lastname: outputFile.write(password[1]) 

merge('file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'output.txt')
```

However, this method isn't very good because it reads a file multiple times. I would go ahead and make a dictionary for the second file, with the lastname as a key. Dictionaries are very helpful in these situations. The dictionary can be made apriori as follows:

```
def makeDict(f2):
  dOut = {}
  with open(f2) as f:
     for l in f:
        dOut[ l.split(':')[0] ] = l.split(':')[1]

  return dOut


def merge(f1,f2,f3):

  pwd = makeDict(f2)
  print pwd
  with open(f3, "a") as outputFile:

     with open(f1) as usernameFile:
        for line in usernameFile:
           if line.strip() == '': continue
           username = line.split(':')[0]
           lastname = line.split(':')[3]
           if lastname in pwd: 
              outputFile.write(username + ':' + pwd[lastname] + '\n')


merge('f1.txt', 'f2.txt', 'f3.txt'  )
```

I just ran the following program using the files:

f1.txt

```
Username0:DOB:Firstname:Lastname0:::
Username1:DOB:Firstname:Lastname1:::
Username2:DOB:Firstname:Lastname2:::
Username3:DOB:Firstname:Lastname3:::
```

f2.txt

```
Lastname0:Password0
Lastname1:Password1
Lastname2:Password2
Lastname3:Password3
```

and got the output:

```
Username0:Password0

Username1:Password1

Username2:Password2

Username3:Password3
```

I did add the last line `merge(...)` and another like which would be used to skip blank lines in the input text, but otherwise, everything should be fine. There wont be any output if the `merge(...` function isn't called.

Comment: `NameError: global name'd' is not defined` ?

Comment: sorry, should be `if lastname in pwd:`

Comment: Please see my update. `I did add the last line merge(...) and another like which would be used to skip blank lines in the input text, but otherwise, everything should be fine.`

Comment: Mine works fine with your example too - but not with the actual files I wish to input? Does it matter that the Lastname in f1.txt is uppercase and lowercase is f2.txt? Maybe thats why its not working?

Comment: Yes, having tested it with your example, if you make the `Lastname` field in either f1 or f2 uppercase, it doesn't output that password. Any advice on how to force the lastname to uppercase in file2.txt? It should hopefully work then.

Comment: You are welcome. I think I am in a different time zone. So there is this 16 hour gap :) always. Anyway, glad that you were able to get it to work. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If the files are identically sorted (i.e. the users appear in the same order in both files), use the [tip in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322419/iterate-across-lines-in-two-files-simultaneously-in-python) to iterate over both files at the same time rather than one after the other in your example.

```
from itertools import izip

with open(f3, "a") as outputFile:
  for line_from_f1, line_from_f2 in izip(open(f1), open(f2)):
    username = line_from_f1.split(':')[0]
    password = line_from_f1.split(':')[1]
    outputfile.write("%s:%s" % (username, password))
```

If the files are not identically sorted, first create a dictionary with keys `lastname` and values `username` from `file1`. Then create a second dictionary with keys `lastname` and values `password` from `file2`. Then iterate over the keys of either dict and print both values.

Comment: Awesome, it works! Can you edit the code so it inputs the printed values into a text file? :) Thanks

Comment: f3.write("%s:%s" % (username, password))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: Ok, maybe sometimes the files are not identically sorted and it causes the data in the third file to become out of alignment, damnit! Thanks for your help but it's back to the drawing board I think as I'm not to sure how to use dictionaries and get this working, haha.

Comment: I've tried it but I'm getting `KeyError: 'blahblahblah'`

Answer (score 1):

Abstract the data extraction from the file i/o, then you can re-use `merge()` with different extraction functions.

```
import itertools as it
from operator import itemgetter    
from contextlib import contextmanager

def extract(foo):
    """Extract username and password, compose and return output string

    foo is a tuple or list
    returns str

    >>> len(foo) == 2
    True
    """
    username = itemgetter(0)
    password = itemgetter(1)
    formatstring = '{}:{}\n'
    item1, item2 = foo
    item1 = item1.strip().split(':')
    item2 = item2.strip().split(':')
    return formatstring.format(username(item1), password(item2))

@contextmanager
def files_iterator(files):
    """Yields an iterator that produces lines synchronously from each file

    Intended to be used with contextlib.contextmanager decorator.
    yields an itertools.izip object

    files is a list or tuple of file paths - str
    """
    files = map(open, files)
    try:
        yield it.izip(*files)
    finally:
        for file in files:
            file.close()


def merge(in_files,out_file, extract):
    """Create a new file with data extracted from multiple files.

    Data is extracted from the same/equivalent line of each file:
        i.e. File1Line1, File2Line1, File3Line1
             File1Line2, File2Line2, File3Line2

    in_files --> list or tuple of str, file paths
    out_file --> str, filepath
    extract --> function that returns list or tuple of extracted data

    returns none
    """
    with files_iterator(in_files) as files, open(out_file, 'w') as out:
        out.writelines(map(extract, files))
##        out.writelines(extract(lines) for lines in files)

merge(['file1.txt', 'file2.txt'], 'file3.txt', extract)
```

`Files_Iterator` is a [With Statement Context Manager](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers) that allows multiple *synchronous* file iteration and ensures the files will be closed.  Here is a good start for reading - [Understanding Python's "with" statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)

Comment: Even improve abstraction by enabling more than two input files. Separate data extraction from output data composition. Basically you have a list of files with extraction properties and compose an output format string that is populated with extracted data. Can you do it? I am going to vote for it.

Comment: I can see the utility of *allowing* more than two input files but the purpose of ```merge``` is to write *finalized* data to a file and ```extract``` will be custom for the files and the data to be extracted, so I think ```extract``` should return the custom formatted data so I'll leave the formatting in it. - see the edit.

Comment: +1 for editing, but the code is now harder to read. The OP is a python beginner and will probably not understand the context manager stuff.

Comment: I didn't understand the context manager stuff till i read about it and tried it and played around with it.

Comment: @SaschaGottfried, see the new edit - I changed the class to a decorated function - seems to improve the readability.

Comment: @wwii When using @contextmanager you need to use try-finally to ensure that errors don't prevent running (it's rethrown at the `try` instead of being passed as an argument).

Comment: @Veedrac I guess that wasn't clear to me from the docs - the docstring might be a better example for the docs - thanks I shoud have thought about it more.  `fyle` was intentional, so I didn't override the built-in, ```file()```, ; it's a habit ...

Comment: @Veedrac I would not have missed it if the example in the docs was like the docstring - but now re-reading the docs, *after-the-fact*, the docs seem pretty clear - I was probably just in a hurry.

Comment: I'm getting `AttributeError: __exit__` - not sure if I'm doing something wrong here though as this is pretty advanced to me. I shall go away and read up about it though.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend building two dictionaries to represent the data in each file, then write File3 based on that structure:

```
d1 = {}
with open("File1.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        d1[line.split(':')[3]] = line.split(':')[0]

d2 = {}
with open("File2.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        d2[line.split(':')[0]] = line.split(':')[1]
```

This will give you two dictionaries that look like this:

```
d1 = {Lastname: Username}
d2 = {Lastname: Password}
```

To then write this to File 3, simply run through the keys of either dicitonary:

```
with open("File3.txt", 'w') as f:
    for key in d1:
        f.write("{}:{}\n".format(d1[key], d2[key]))
```

Some things to Note:

- If the files don't have all the same values, you'll need to throw in some handling for that (let me know if this is the case and I can toss a few ideas your way
- This approach does not preserve any order the files were in
- The code assumes that all lines are of the same format.  A more complicated file will need some code to handle "odd" lines

Answer (score 0):

Its fine to avoid this if you have identically sorted rows in each file. But, if it gets any more complicated than that, then you should be using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) for this. With pandas, you can essentially do a join, so, no matter how the rows are ordered in each file, this will work. Its also very concise.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv(f1, sep=':', header=None).ix[:,[0,3]]
df1.columns = ['username', 'lastname']
df2 = pd.read_csv(f2, sep=':', header=None)
df2.columns = ['lastname', 'password']
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2).ix[:,['username','password']]
df3.to_csv(f3, header=False, index=False, sep=':')
```

Note that you will also have the option to do outer joins. This is useful, if for some reason, there are usernames without passwords or vice versa in your files.

Comment: Improve your answer by showing input data that will break solutions given by others but work perfectly with yours since pandas is a perfect fit.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty close.  Be sure no blank line at end of input files, or add code to skip blank lines when you read.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
File 1:
Username:DOB:Firstname:Lastname:::

File2:
Lastname:Password

File3:
Username:Password

"""

def merge(f1,f2,f3):
   username_lastname = {}
   with open(f3, "a") as outputFile:
      with open(f1) as usernameFile:
         for line in usernameFile:
            user = line.strip().split(':')
            print user
            username_lastname[user[3]] = user[0] # dict with Lastname as key, Username as value

      print username_lastname      
      with open(f2) as passwordFile:
         for line in passwordFile:
            lastname_password = line.strip().split(':')
            print lastname_password
            password = lastname_password[1]
            username = username_lastname[lastname_password[0]]
            print username, password
            out_line = "%s:%s\n" % (username, password)
            outputFile.write(out_line)
         outputFile.close()

merge('f1.txt', 'f2.txt', 'output.txt')

f1:
Username1:DOB:Firstname:Lastname1:::
Username2:DOB:Firstname:Lastname2:::
Username3:DOB:Firstname:Lastname3:::

f2:
Lastname1:Password1
Lastname2:Password2
Lastname3:Password3

f3: 
Username1:Password1
Username2:Password2
Username3:Password3
```