# Context Manager Type that iterates over multiple files - testing

Tags: python, contextmanager

Id like to use `itertools.izip()` to iterate over the lines of multiple files.  I have made a context manager type to ensure all the files will be closed when used with `with`.
This seems to work:

```
class Files_Iterator(object):
    """Sequential line iteration from multiple files
    """
    def __init__(self, files):
        """files --> list or tuple of str, file paths
        """
        self.files = files
    def __enter__(self):
        print 'opening files'
        self.files = map(open, self.files)
        return it.izip(*self.files)
    def __exit__(self, *exception_args):
        print 'closing files'
        for arg in exception_args:
            print arg,
        for thing in self.files:
            thing.close()
        return False
```

Two questions:

1. Have I implemented this correctly?
2. Can I test this to ensure the files are getting closed or do I just trust it?

I used print statements to signal when `__exit__` is called - is that a sufficient test?

```
>>> with Files_Iterator(['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']) as files:
    for lines in files:
        print lines
        raise Exception


opening files
('File1Line1\n', 'File2Line1\n')
closing files
<type 'exceptions.Exception'>  <traceback object at 0x0313DFD0>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#48>", line 4, in <module>
    raise Exception
Exception
>>>
```

Comment: You're probably aware that this will keep all the files open at the same time. If you're sure the files are only used sequentially, returning a custom iterator could make sure that only one file is open at a time, and the `with` on the outside can deal with cleanup of that last (single) file.

Comment: FWIW, this can be nicer written with the `contextlib.contextmanager` convenience class.

Comment: @Veedrac, The intent is to produce lines from each file so - I didn't actually think about (make a decision) whether all the files should stay open at the same time.  I looked at ```contextlib.contextmanager``` - I'm not sure why I didn't go that route.

Comment: @Veedrac, you are correct, a decorated function is much easier to read (for me at least). I used it here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/24702096/2823755

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks fine, yes you can trust it, but I would explicitly name the arguments to `__exit__`:

```
def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
    print 'closing files'
    for arg in (exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print arg,
    for f in self.files:
        f.close()
    return False # does not suppress the exception.
```

And when the function exits, if there is an exception, it will be processed normally.