# Python double for function

Tags: python

I built this Python code with the intent to match each first name with the last name:

```
first_names = ['Jane','Sam','Deborah']
last_names = ['Simmons','Kaybone','Stone']

for f_name in first_names:
    for l_name in last_names:
        print(f_name.title() + " " + l_name.title())
```

But apparently my code prints out all first names with all last_names instead of just (1,1), (2,2), (3,3). How do I tweak this code? Thanks!

Comment: You just built a nested loop

Comment: `print (*((f,l) for f,l in zip(first_names,last_names)))`

Comment: If you wanted to print out `(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)` how would you expect to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem in looping two for loops at the same time in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55558467/problem-in-looping-two-for-loops-at-the-same-time-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
first_names = ['Jane','Sam','Deborah']
last_names = ['Simmons','Kaybone','Stone']
for f, l in zip(first_names, last_names):
    print(f.title(),l.title())
```

Output:

```
Jane Simmons
Sam Kaybone
Deborah Stone
```

One-liner:

```
print(*(f'{f.title()} {l.title()}' for f, l in zip(first_names, last_names)),sep='\n')
```

**EDIT**:
As pointed correctly by [Peter Wood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59301566/python-double-for-function/59301595?noredirect=1#comment104806272_59301595):

```
print(*(f'{f} {l}'.title() for f, l in zip(first_names, last_names)),sep='\n')
```

Comment: Why not call `str.title` once?

Comment: Just slipped my mind. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
first_names = ['Jane','Sam','Deborah']
last_names = ['Simmons','Kaybone','Stone']

for f_name, l_name in zip(first_names, last_names):
  print(f_name + " " + l_name)
```